# How to compress multiple subfolders into separate files in linux?

Tags: linux, zip

I have following directory:

1. Folder_A

   - Folder_A1
2. Folder_B

   - Folder_B1

---

I would like to zip sub-folders, so at the end I will have something like this:

1. Folder_A1.zip
2. Folder_B1.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the folders like this:

```
for folder in Folder_*/Folder*; do
  cd "${folder%/*}"
  zip -r ../"${folder#*/}.zip" "${folder#*/}"
  cd ..
done
```

Comment: Thanks you for reply, Can I keep only Folder_A1 in zip file, not like Folder_A/Folder_A1 inside zip? Also can I run this script with having any pattern in folder names?

Comment: @user1812750 I edited the answer as requested: You will have to go down to the child folder and zip the grandchild folder there and get back up. And of course you can adapt the glob (`*`) pattern do meet your needs.